# Pywin32: method "restrict" of outlook Items object to get appointments don't work in my code

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, pywin32

Problem: restrict method shows me result, which I don't aspect:
MSDN Documentation to this method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict

Hi guys,

i'm trying to read appointments in Outlook 2017 with pywin32 in python (OS: Win7 x64, location: Germany). 
This is my code which I use:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime
outlookinst=win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
ns=outlookinst.GetNamespace("MAPI")
existappointments=ns.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items
begin=datetime.date.today()
print(begin)
end = begin+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(end)
restriction="[Start] >= '" + begin.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "' AND [End] <=    '" +end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "'"
existappointments = existappointments.Restrict(restriction)   
nCnt=1
if (existappointments !=None):
for index in existappointments :
    print(existappointments .Item(nCnt).Subject,existappointments .Item(nCnt).Start)
    nCnt=nCnt+1
```

in my outlook there three test appointments for today (2019/02/08):

```
subject: test1, start: 2019.02.08 8:30 end: 2019.02.08 9:00
subject: test2, start: 2019.02.08 10:00 end: 2019.02.08 10:30
subject: test3, start: 2019.02.08 8:30 end: 2019.02.08 9:00
```

the result of my code:

```
2019-02-08
2019-02-09
xxxxx 2019-01-15 08:30:00+00:00 (xxxx for subject)
xxxxx 2017-07-14 11:15:00+00:00
xxxxx 2019-01-22 16:15:00+00:00
```

maybe I have to consider the UTC time problem? but I don't know really how to make this work correctly.

can anyone maybe give me some suggestions? thanks a lot.

one point to add:

if I don't use the restrict method, then i can see this three test appointments as result:

```
...
test1 2019-02-08 08:30:00+00:00
test2 2019-02-08 10:00:00+00:00
test3 2019-02-08 13:00:00+00:00
```